# jQuery Dim or change other list items on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

How could I go about changing color on hover and at the same time dim the rest to a different color and/or opacity.

A simple three list items enclosed within it's unordered list.

These list items change color on hover.

Code:

```
.right-side .headlines li a,.right-side .headlines li{font-size:36px;color:#999}
.right-side .headlines li a:hover{color:#0976ca}

<ul class="headlines">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Headline 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Headline 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Headline 3</a>
    </li>           
</ul>
```

Thanks Guys

Comment: something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/nJ8qG/1

Comment: This works excellent. jQuery siblings answer works too. Maybe this approach lighter on client side? @Sotiris Thanks

Comment: A CSS only solution is of course much lighter than a javascript framework.

Comment: It is lighter. Depends on the effect you want to achieve. For nice-looking effects... here it is: jQuery! 21th century... right? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Cav6t/57/)**

**CSS:**

```
.headlines a{
    font-size:36px;
    color:#999;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
.headlines:hover a{            /* PARENT HOVER */
    opacity:0.4;               /* Dim all */
}    
.headlines       a:hover{      /* SINGLE HOVER */
    opacity: 1;                /* Max one */
    color:#0976ca;
}
```